# How to auto-refresh an iframe if src = X using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, refresh

I'm trying to write a code which will auto-refresh an `iframe` window if the `src='http://www.url.com'`, else if the iframe source is different then don't auto-refresh.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamster.

Comment: So you knew what I meant then? It's been changed. Any idea how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you had post some code that you try.

You need to set an id to your your iframe and get it using getElementById

```
var myIframe = document.getElementById("myIframe");
```

To auto refresh with a predetermined interval, you will need `setInterval`
To verify that your iframe source is the desired one, usae an if statement:

```
setInterval
( function()
     { 
     if ( myIframe.src == "http://www.url.com" )
         myIframe.src = myIframe.src; 
     }, 60000 );
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/44WJG/) is a jsfiddle that auto-refresh the iframe at each 60 seconds if the source is the one specified

Comment: thanks for the response. This is run onload though right so if you set the iframe to the page you want to refresh, it'll refresh the iframe even if you navigate to another page right? I need it to refresh if it's that page in the iframe, but then if the page changes to not be that page, stop refreshing. Any idea how to do that? Thanks again.

Comment: The 60 seconds auto-refresh interval starts onload of the current page. Not called onload of the iframe. Each minute, it will check the iframe URL to verify that it it the predetermined URL to refresh. If it is changed, it will not refresh anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME");
    for(var i=0;i<els.length;++i) {
        if(els[i].src=="http://www.url.com/") {
            els[i].contentWindow.document.location.href = els[i].contentWindow.document.location.href;
        }
    }
},1000);
```

1000 mean's - every one second.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. Sorry I'm a total Newb. I've set it up in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qMvzQ/1/ but I can't get it to work. Any idea what's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I fixed it here: http://jsfiddle.net/qMvzQ/2/. first bug - if you want to refresh one frame only, use **document.getElementById(yourID)**, if you want to refresh all franme, use **document.getElementsByTagName(youtTagName)**. second bug - if it external url, you cannot use **contentWindow**, jush **src** (like morgul wrote...)

Comment: Thanks inon. I just need one frame. When I navigate to another page or domain in that iframe it continues to refresh though. How can I limit the refresh to just be on the one page url?

Comment: If it;s an internal url, you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/yWccb/1/. If it's external, I think you cann't do that, He gives security error because you try to get info from antoher domain...